# Do I need a visa for entering Georgia?

Tags: visas, usa, schengen, georgia-country, bangladeshi-citizens

I am a Bangladeshi passport holder. I have an USA visa for up to 5 years validity with multiple entries and a Schengen visa for a month's validity. Do I need a visa for entering Georgia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No, you don't: if you've used your USA visa at least once, you can enter Georgia visa-free for 90 days.**

> Foreign nationals who have a multiple entry US, EU or Schengen member states visas, which have validity for one year or more and had been used once at least, can enter or stay on the territory of Georgia without visa up to 90 days, within the validity term of the visa.

Source: http://italy.mfa.gov.ge/index.php?lang_id=ENG&sec_id=844